# EMC Solution Enabler

Tags: storage, san, emc

I would like to install EMC Solution Enabler on RHEL 7.1 and 86_64.
Please advice which version is supported with this configuration.

Note: I want to have this software because I would like to use 'syminq'  command to get storage information in the host.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't look like its supported on RHEL 7.1 . The latest seems to be RedHat Enterprise Linux 6.0/6.2 , as per the below latest release document :
http://uk.emc.com/collateral/TechnicalDocument/docu61129.pdf

It mentions that Solutions Enabler V8.1 installation requires i686 version of 
glibc (GNU C Library) and libgcc (Library of GCC support routines) packages pre-installed. If your RHEL 7.1 host doesn't have the those , it also mentions of a work around. Hopefully it should work for RHEL 7.1 too.